# system() to c# without calling cmd.exe

Tags: c#, c, cmd

how to translate system("") to C# without calling cmd.exe?
edit: i need to throw something like "dir"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other folks noted, it's **[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)**. Example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// ...

Process.Start(@"C:\myapp\foo.exe");
```

Comment: What would be the working directory if you call `Process.Start(@"C:\myapp\foo.exe");` as such?

Answer (score 8):

If I correctly understood your question, you're looking for [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx).

See this example (from the docs):

```
// Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer.
void OpenWithArguments()
{
    // url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
    // by passing them as arguments.
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

    // Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.asp");
 }
```

**Edit**

As you said you needed something like the "dir" command, I would suggest you to take a look at [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_members(v=VS.100).aspx). You can use it to create your own directory listing. For example (also from the docs):

```
// Create a DirectoryInfo of the directory of the files to enumerate.
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\archives1\library");

DateTime StartOf2009 = new DateTime(2009, 01, 01);

// LINQ query for all files created before 2009.
var files = from f in DirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
           where DirInfo.CreationTimeUtc < StartOf2009
           select f;

// Show results.
foreach (var f in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", f.Name);
}
```

Comment: And you should avoid system() in first place in your original C application.

Comment: dir was just an example i want to simulate cmd.exe

Comment: Whatever were you trying to achieve with system, there's almost certainly a cleaner way to do that directly from C/C#. *system* is a function to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

```
I need to throw something like "dir"
```

If you need to run DIR, then you need to call cmd.exe as dir is internal to cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question. Are you looking for `Process.Start`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *actually* want the equivalent? You may not depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

For example calling `copy` from the command line has a C# equivalent itself, [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx), for `dir` there's a whole [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ta62wh3(v=VS.100).aspx) class for getting info (these are a quick 2 out of thousands of examples).  Depending on what you're after, C# most likely has a library/function for the *specific* command you're trying to run, usually a more robust method as well, instead of a global handler.

If the global "invoke this" is what you're after, then as the other answers suggest, using the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3s566a.aspx) class is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a command-line (cmd.exe) command, such as "dir" or "time" or "mkdir", pass the command as an argument to cmd.exe with the flag /C.

For example,

```
cmd.exe /C dir
```

or

```
cmd.exe /C mkdir "New Dir"
```