# system() to c++ without calling cmd.exe

Tags: c++, c, cmd

how can I run system("") without showing cmd.exe?

I use cstdlib header
code::blocks 10.5

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794386/system-to-c-without-calling-cmd-exe) for c# but I don't know c# ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide console in C system() function, Win.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597289/hide-console-in-c-system-function-win)

Comment: Actually, you're not hiding cmd.exe, you're hiding the command prompt. CMD is just an interpreter. The actual command window itself is provided by Windows NT (specifically csrss.exe on Vista and earlier, and csrss.exe and conhost.exe on 7 and later). That's why all console programs, not just cmd.exe, use the same console window type. </Pedantry>

Answer (score 6):

I believe you'll have to go with [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: ``CreateProcess`` seems to be only for windows and will not work on Linux or Mac. Any way to fix it with the standard ``system()`` function?

Comment: Please feel free to apecify the target platform in your question. However, cmd.exe is very much Windows specific. There is no simple answer that will work on all platforms since you are asking for functionality outside of the standard library.

Comment: But this problem is just in windows. In unix, a **Terminal** (or Console) is something separated from **Shell**. So no terminal window will be apeared when calling a shell command. I was not the asker of this topic, but suppose we are writing an application for all platforms (and It works), but we don't like to it open a terminal in Windows when calling `system()`.

Comment: @ilius It sounds like you have a candidate for a new question. This one is implicitly targeted at Windows.

Comment: @ilius In your case, you'll probably need some `#ifdef`s.

Answer (score 1):

I must say, the existing answer wasn't particularly descriptive. Here's a way to execute commands without a new `cmd.exe` window.

Based on [an answer by Roland Rabien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597315/6850771) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), I've written a working function:

```
int windows_system(const char *cmd)
{
  PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
  STARTUPINFO s_info;
  LPSTR cmdline, programpath;

  memset(&s_info, 0, sizeof(s_info));
  memset(&p_info, 0, sizeof(p_info));
  s_info.cb = sizeof(s_info);

  cmdline     = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));
  programpath = _tcsdup(TEXT(cmd));

  if (CreateProcess(programpath, cmdline, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &s_info, &p_info))
  {
    WaitForSingleObject(p_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(p_info.hThread);
  }
}
```

Works on all Windows platforms. Call just like you would `system()`.