# Starting a hidden C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a C++ program with Visual Studio 2010 that is supposed to run on the background of my machine.

Therefore when I start it, I shouldn't see the CMD screen while it is running. How can I do this? Do I have to use the Win32 API or a normal C++ program will suffice?

Please note that my program has no GUI at all.

Comment: I asked it before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875995/system-to-c-without-calling-cmd-exe

Comment: It probably requires some Windows specific API - I have no idea which (only using Linux and knowing Posix, but not Win32).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Use WinMain() :**

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst,HINSTANCE prev,LPSTR cmd,int show)
{
  // program starts here
  return 0;
}

// int main()  <-- remove main()
```

Then ake sure your project settings are set so that you build a "Win32" program and not a "Console" program.

[image]

**Edit:** As @Sehe points out, winMain may not be necessary, although I am not quite sure where this option lies.

Comment: Using WinMain has _nothing_ to do with that. Just alter the subsystem option to Win32 and you're done.

Comment: @sehe: If you do that in Visual Studio, the default entry point is changed to WinMain.

Comment: @sehe Your *suggestion* is wrong. This will resolve in :error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: Oh, I'm oldschool :) I use `EDITBIN /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS test.exe` (or, actually, usually pass that option directly to the linker (CL)

Comment: @sehe I didn't mean to shout. But I also tested that and I got the error I told you. Said error went away with winMain. Definitely both ways are possible/correct.

Comment: @FailedDev: please don't shout when you are not sure. I'm not wrong: I just _tested_ that. No entry points got changed. I'm sure Visual Studio will have a corresponding flag somewhere buried in it's dialogs. I'm sorry I can't give you info on _that_ right now. **PS** The reason I care, is that it can be a Royal™ PainInTheAss® to handle posix-ly command line arguments with `WinMain` style entrypoint

Comment: @FailedDev: Both ways _exist_. What is correct is determined by context. I'll reduce the claim: WinMain hasn't _necessarily_ got anything to do with that :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, it was just what I was looking for! :)

Comment: And , if you need a message loop, you can always create a message only window , that has no gui interface at all, but does have a winproc:)

Answer (score 5):

Run it as a service [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Very often a program running under Windows without a "face" (eg, with no user interface at all) is implemented as a [Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40xe80wx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In windows, [Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) programs are implemented as [Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).

Answer (score 1):

Simply make it a GUI application instead of a command line application. Right click the project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem -> Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS).

Answer (score 0):

You can run as a Windows process (which doesn't attach to a console), but never create a window. the main difference is the signature of `WinMain`, and the flags to the compiler.

Go to File -> New Project, select the standard Windows Application, then delete everything except `WinMain`.